# New Login Page, Global Network Login not Working

Tags: bug, login

I used to be able to login to one Stack Exchange website, then later, in the same browser session, visit another and click log in, and I would be logged in without having to enter my username and password. I noticed with thew new log in page I have to renter my credentials. Is this a bug?

Comment: Also doesn’t work for me with the new login page anymore. I don’t know why, but some sites still have the old login page which works fine.